# Can not upload image to google cloud bucket using c# windows application

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

Hello I have created a windows application which uploads image from hdd to google cloud server.
My code was working perfectly but after changing bucket name it is not working.
My both buckets are in the same project and I have given OAuth 2.0 to my project.

even there is no error showing while processing. Please help me.

```
            string bucketForImage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BucketName"];
            string projectName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"];
            string Accountemail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"];
            var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
            clientSecrets.ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
            clientSecrets.ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

            string gcpPath = @"D:\mrunal\tst_mrunal.png";

            var scopes = new[] { @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control" };
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var userCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, scopes, Accountemail, cts.Token);
            var service = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService();
            var bucketToUpload = bucketForImage;
            var newObject = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
            {
                Bucket = bucketToUpload,
                Name = "mrunal.png"
            };

            fileStream = new FileStream(gcpPath, FileMode.Open);
            var uploadRequest = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(service, newObject,
            bucketToUpload, fileStream, "image/png");
            uploadRequest.OauthToken = userCredential.Token.AccessToken;
            await uploadRequest.UploadAsync();
            //uploadRequest.UploadAsync();
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: I have tried debugging the code. No error is showing. also put this code in try catch function but process completes successfully but in bucket no image is uploaded.

Comment: Did you try this same code for the older bucket and it worked? It seems to me that there is an issue with line of code, uploadRequest.OauthToken = userCredential.Token.AccessToken. You are calling the Token.AccessToken directly from the userCredentials. These methods should be called from the [userCredentials.Result](https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2GoogleRegularAccountsInstalledApps.html#tabs02).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this same code for the older bucket and it worked? It seems to me that there is an issue with line of code, uploadRequest.OauthToken = userCredential.Token.AccessToken. You are calling the Token.AccessToken directly from the userCredentials. These methods should be called from the [userCredentials.Result](https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2GoogleRegularAccountsInstalledApps.html#tabs02).